# Ruby on Rails |param is missing or the value is empty: task|

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm newbie in rails.
For my first project, I decided creat "To Do" app. 
After 2 hours, I backed down.
My controller:

```
def complete_todo
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    @task.complete_task = true
    if @task.update_attributes(task_params)
        redirect_to root_path
    end
end

private
def task_params
    params.require(:task).permit(:name,
                                 :description,
                                 :start_on,
                                 :finish_date,
                                 :repeat,
                                 :complete_task)
end
```

my routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'tasks#index'
  resources :tasks
  get 'create_new_task',  to: 'tasks#new'
  get 'complete',         to: 'tasks#complete'
  post 'tasks/complete_todo/:id',    to: 'tasks#complete_todo', as: 'finished_task'
end
```

and my view

```
- @tasks.each do |task|
    - if task.complete_task == false
        div class="panel panel-primary"
            div class="panel-heading"               
                h3 class="panel-title" = link_to task.name, task_path(task)     
            div class="panel-body" 
                div class="col-md-11"
                    = task.description
                div class="col-md-1"
                    div class="bs-glyphicons"
                        = link_to finished_task_path(task), method: :post do
                            div class="col-md-6"
                                span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"
                        = link_to task_path(task), method: :delete do
                            div class="col-md-6"
                                span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"
```

I would like write more, but my writing skill in english is awful =(

Comment: I think that the problem in the route. Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

I find answer.
Edit controller:

```
def complete_todo
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    @task.complete_task = true
    if @task.save
        redirect_to root_path
    end
end
```

And edit routes:

```
 post 'tasks/:id/complete_todo', to: 'tasks#complete_todo', as: 'finished_task'
```